# Child Form getting properties from multiple parent Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Can I get query value from two parents (`FrmMasterItem` and `FrmMasterPackage`) for one Form (`FrmItemSearch`) that contains a DataGridView and pass the selected value to its parent Form?

I've already tried tto have `FrmItemSearch` get some data from `FrmMasterItem` and it can show the data, but I want `FrmItemSearch` to get data from `FrmMasterPackage` too, so I only need one Form with a DataGridView to perform all the search operations.

```
//this is my MasterItem Form
public partial class FrmMasterItem : Form
{
      public string myQuery { get; set; }
      public FrmMasterItem() { InitializeComponent(); }

      public void SearchItemCode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
            this.myQuery = "select * from InItemMst";

            FrmItemSearch fcd = new FrmItemSearch(this);
            fcd.ShowDialog();
      }
}


//this is my MasterPackage Form
public partial class FrmMasterPackage : Form 
{
    public string sQuery { get; set; }
    public FrmMasterPackage() { InitializeComponent(); }

    public void SearchItemCode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          this.sQuery = "select * from InPackagehdr";
          //I want to get this query on FrmSearchItem
    }
}  

//this is my Item Search Form
public partial class FrmItemSearch : Form
{
      private FrmMasterItem f_mb;
      public FrmItemSearch(FrmMasterItem fmb)
      {
            f_mb = fmb;
            InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void FrmItemSearch_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
            MySqlConnection conn = DBUtils.GetDbConnection();
            conn.Open();

            string query = this.f_mb.myQuery;//this is only MasterItem Data i want to make some selection for MasterPackage here so the Gridview can View MasterPackage data using sQuery Value from FrmMasterPackage

            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
            bSource.DataSource = dt;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
      }
}
```

Comment: `f_mb` is [not a nice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-type-members#names-of-fields) name.

Comment: i dont know what name should i use, just testing some code :) btw im new in C#

Comment: You can pass the current caller (one of the *master* Forms) query string in the child (the *search* Form) constructor. Give or take what you're doing now, just passing a string instead of a Form. Or make you Form objects implement a *contract resolver* Interface, exposing a know property: a property set to the query string, so you don't need to know what Form opened the Search, you just need to know that it must implement that interface, thus exposing that property. The form in question can be the *Seach* Owner. (you create a Form specifying the Owner with `var someForm = new SomeForm(this)`)

Comment: thanks for your advice but i need to get more than 1 value from each master form so i just want to know is it possible to get 2 master form in my search form

Comment: Define an Interface with more than one property :) Or a property/method that returns a complex object (a class, a JSON etc.).

Comment: can u show me the example of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example using an [Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface), to define a *contract* that relates a class (a Form, here) to another.

Since you have more than one class (Forms) that need use another class (your `Search` Form) to perform the same task using common properties and methods, the *worker* class (the `Search` Form) doesn't need to know which class instantiated it, it just need to rely on the Interface implementation and use the common properties and methods to read the values it needs and write its results.

Create an Interface that defines the properties and methods that create the *contract* (what all the involved classes need to know and rely upon):

```
internal interface ISearch
{
    string Query { get; }
    int Other { get; }
    bool ReturnValue { get; set; }

    string GetSomeOtherValue();
}
```

All the Forms that want to call the `Search` Form must implement the **`ISearch`** interface:

```
public class FrmMasterItem : Form, ISearch
{
    public FrmMasterItem() => InitializeComponent();

    // Interface implementation
    public string Query { get; private set; }
    public int Other { get ; private set; }
    public bool ReturnValue { get; set; }

    public string GetSomeOtherValue()
    {
        return "SomeValue";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Query = "SELECT someField FROM someTable";
        this.Other = 100;
        var search = new SearchForm();
        search.ShowDialog(this);
        if (this.ReturnValue)
            Console.WriteLine("All Good");
    }
}
```

Here, on a `Button.Click` event, the properties defined by the Interface are set, the `Search` Form is initialized and shown, setting the `Search` Form current [Owner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.owner):

```
var search = new SearchForm();
search.ShowDialog(this);
```

When the `Search` Form is closed, a value set by the `Search` Form (here, the **`ReturnValue`** propeprty value) is read to determine the result of the search.
Of course you could return anything alse or set more than one property: you could return a DataTable, for example.

The Search Form defines the current caller Form using the Interface:

```
ISearch myOwner = null;
```

Then verifies whether the current owner implements this interface: it must know if it can rely on properties and methods defined by the *contract*.

```
Type type = this.Owner.GetType();
if (typeof(ISearch).IsAssignableFrom(type)) {
    // (...)
    myOwner = (ISearch)this.Owner;
}
```

If the current owner doesn't implement the trusted Interface, then an exception is thrown: the `Search` Form cannot read and write the required values.
If it does, initializes inself reading the values from the known properties (some usual checks, i.e., `null` or type-related, are of course needed).
When closing, it sets the result using a specific property (**`ReturnValue`**, here):

```
myOwner.ReturnValue = true;
base.OnFormClosing(e);
```

The `Search` Form:

```
public partial class SearchForm : Form
{
    ISearch myOwner = null;
    string currentQuery = string.Empty;
    string otherValues = string.Empty;

    public SearchForm() => InitializeComponent();

    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        Type type = this.Owner.GetType();
        if (typeof(ISearch).IsAssignableFrom(type))
        {
            myOwner = (ISearch)this.Owner;
            this.currentQuery = myOwner.Query;
            this.otherValues = myOwner.GetSomeOtherValue();
            Console.WriteLine(this.currentQuery);
            Console.WriteLine(myOwner.Other);
            Console.WriteLine(this.otherValues);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("My Owner is not the right type!");
        }
    }
    protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        myOwner.ReturnValue = true;
        base.OnFormClosing(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: can u tell me how to get the datagridview value, since my search form is using datagridview, i want to pass the selected value from datagridview back to my textbox on its Owner form, sorry if i ask too much.. @Jimi

Comment: It depends on what you want to return. In the example, `ReturnValue` is a `bool`, but you can define it as you want. Maybe, set it to return a string instead. You can assign it the `[DataGridView].CurrentCell.Value.ToString()`, for example. When the `Search` Form is closed, the Form that opened it will have the selected value in `ReturnValue` and you can assign it to a TextBox (or anything else that accepts a string).

Comment: i want to return the selected id value from my search form for my master form textbox, if i double click the row header on datagridview, then the datagridview will closed and pass the selected id value to my masterForm IdTextBox

Comment: Well, then subscribe to the `RowHeaderMouseDoubleClick` and assign to `ReturnValue` the correct cell value of the selected Row:  `[DataGridView].Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[X].Value.ToString()` where `X` is the index or the name of the Column that holds the value you want to return.

Comment: `f_mb.txtItemId.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();`
i do it like this, but it said "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Nope. You cannot assign that value to the Form directly. Assign it to `ReturnValue`. When the Search Form closes, the Form that opened it will read `ReturnValue` and assign it to whatever control needs it.

Comment: can you show me the example of code  ?, i have tried ur solution to return the value but it still says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Of course I cannot know what this exception is referring to because you didn't mention it. I assumed that you actually used the code I posted here. It appears that you didn't. Maybe, post another question, showing what is the code that you have implemented, which object raises the exception and in what context.

Comment: dude now i get it how it works !!, really dude thanks for your advice, and sorry for making u tilted :D

Answer (score 1):

just declare your myQuery variable as below in master form

```
public static string myQuery
```

and then you can access this variable to any form using master's object

Comment: that myQuery is fine with the FrmItemSearch, what i want to do is to make my sQuery on FrmMasterPackage can be used too on FrmItemSearch

Comment: static means that only one instance of a given variable exists for a class. Static variables are used to define constants because their values can be retrieved by invoking the class without creating an instance of it. Static variables can be initialized outside the member function or class definition

Answer (score 0):

May I also add that it's considered bad practice to add DAL (Data Access Layer) or BLL (Business Logic Layer) code to your Forms? I suggest creating directories and classes for such code.

I suggest the following:

```
public partial class FrmItemSearch : Form
{
      private FrmMasterItem f_mb;
      public FrmItemSearch(FrmMasterItem fmb)
      {
            f_mb = fmb;
            InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void FrmItemSearch_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
            ataGridView1.DataSource = DAL.GetSourceFromDatabase(DAL.query);
      }
}

public static class DAL
{
    public static string query = "MyQuery"

    public static BindingSource GetSourceFromDatabase(string query)
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = DBUtils.GetDbConnection();
        conn.Open();
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
        bSource.DataSource = dt;
        return dt;
    }
}
```