# Bring at front Parent form and maintain list count which comming from child form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have to form "SalesProduct" and "SearchProduct". In "SalesProduct" Form there is on datagridview when i click at datagridview cell/Column name "Product name" then "SearchProduct" form will open where i search item select item row from datagridview checkbox button then click at Select button then i want it should hide/close "SearchProduct" button and bring at front parent "SalesProduct" form.

It also get data in list from "searchProduct" form to "SalesProduct" form and add a row in "SalesProduct" form. When I again click Product column it will again open "searchProduct" form and select row from it then close after clicking Select button and bring at front "SalesProduct" form and add this new row in the form and not remove other rows which i add previously.

My problem is that "SalesProduct" form is not coming at front when "SearchProduct" form close it is opening new form and it also remove other rows which i put into "SalesProduct" form previously.

My code is below. Kindly help me how to maintain count and bring at front parent form without creating new instance.

,,,,

```
public partial class SaleProduct_Form : Form
{
  public List<CommenValue_Class> value { get; set; } 

  public SaleProduct_Form()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

 private void gridSalesProduct_CellEnter(
    object sender, 
    DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
 {
   if (gridSalesProduct.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1)
   {
     SearchProduct_Form searchProduct = new SearchProduct_Form();
     searchProduct.ShowDialog(this);
   }
 }

private void SaleProduct_Form_Load(
   object sender, 
   EventArgs e)
{
  addToGrid(value);                
}

public void addToGrid(List<CommenValue_Class> val)
{
  if (val != null)
  {

    foreach (CommenValue_Class item in val)
    {
      int n = gridSalesProduct.Rows.Add();    
      gridSalesProduct.Rows[n].Cells["ProductName"].Value = item.Product_Name;
      gridSalesProduct.Rows[n].Cells["Balance"].Value = item.Qty_Balance;
      gridSalesProduct.Rows[n].Cells["Rate"].Value = item.Rate;    
     }
    }
  }
}


public partial class SearchProduct_Form : Form
{
  public SearchProduct_Form()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  private void btnSelectProduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    try
    {
      List<CommenValue_Class> CV = new List<CommenValue_Class>();

      foreach (DataGridViewRow item in gridProductList.Rows)
      {
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(item.Cells[0].Value))
        {
          CV.Add(new CommenValue_Class
          {
            Product_Name = item.Cells["Product_Name"].Value.ToString(),
            Qty_Balance = Convert.ToInt32( item.Cells["Balance_Qty"].Value.ToString()),
            Rate = Convert.ToDecimal (item.Cells["Per_Unit_Sale_Price"].Value.ToString())
          });
        }
      }

      SaleProduct_Form saleProduct = new SaleProduct_Form();
      saleProduct.value = CV;
      saleProduct.Show();
      this.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { 
      MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should not do this in your `SearchProduct_Form`  
`SaleProduct_Form saleProduct = new SaleProduct_Form();
      saleProduct.value = CV;
      saleProduct.Show();`
because it will create a new instance of `SaleProduct_Form`. Instead, create a `SaleProduct_Form_FormClosed` event in `SaleProduct_Form` and assign the selected value after `SearchProduct_Form` is closed.

Comment: but when i select one row and it is added into salesProduct_Form, after that i will try to add one an other row then previous row will discard from SalesProduct_Form

Comment: Basically, your logic is wrong. `SaleProduct_Form` should be the only main form running, on `cell_clicked` you can show `SearchProduct_Form` in a dialog, and when it closes, get the returning value.

Comment: You have to remove this: `SaleProduct_Form saleProduct = new SaleProduct_Form();` this creates a new Form, unrelated to the one you're currently showing. See this [reusable Search Form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56165975/7444103), using an Interface to determine the contract between the Search Form and other Forms which make use of its *services*. You can find a gazillion other examples related to data exchange between Forms.